# How to break a stalemate in Hive?

Tags: hive

My wife and I are playing it first game of Hive, and we're a little confused on how to win.  We're playing without the mosquitoes and ladybugs as the directions suggested. Given the game below, couldn't white's grasshoppers just surround the queen bee indefinitely? What would force them to move?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [rules](http://www.gen42.com/downloads/rules/Hive_Rules.pdf), p11 (see also p1):

> The game ends as soon as one Queen Bee is completely surrounded by pieces of **any color.**

So the situation you depict is not a stalemate - it's an immediate victory for Black.

Comment: Oh wow, well that changes things. That makes so much more sense. Thanks for the clarification!